# If $ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\ -a & -1 & c \\ -b & -c & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, show that $detA=1+a^2+b^2+c^2$. Hence, find $A^{-1}$ for any a,b, and c.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

**If $ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\ -a & -1 & c \\ -b & -c & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, show that $detA=1+a^2+b^2+c^2$. Hence, find $A^{-1}$ for any a,b, and c.**

Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

---

Using Rule of Sarrus I can confirm:
$detA=b^2+c^2+a^2+1-acb+bac=1+a^2+b^2+c^2$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the formula for a 3 by 3 determinant or do you have to do it only by elementary row/column operations?

Comment: As in the Rule of Sarrus?

Comment: Yes, or any other formula for calculating the determinant of a matrix. For example, Laplace's formula which is probably the most well-known one expresses the determinant of an n by n matrix in terms of minors and cofactors. Do you know that formula?

Comment: I know both. While waiting for your response I've confirmed that $det(A)=1+a^2+b^2+c^2$ using the Rule of Sarrus. I will add it above. But I'm still not sure what finding $A^{-1}$ will do or how to find it for any $a,b,c.$

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-minors-cofactors-adjugate.html

Comment: Once you know the determinant of an n by n matrix, there's a formula to find its inverse by algebraic manipulation constructing the adjugate matrix of $A$ and dividing by the determinant. It's messy but it's manageable for 3 by 3 matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to let you find the determinant of $A$  it is pretty straight forward to calculate the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix, and if you don't know it yet, it is worth looking up.

$A^{-1}$

One way to do it is to take $A$ put the indentity matrix next to it.
Perform row operations on $A$ and perform the identical operations on $I$
When you have reduced $A$ to the identity, what was the identity has become $A^{-1}$

Another idea.  The second and third row vectors of $A$ are both orthogonal to the first column vector of $A^{-1}$

if you find $(-a, -1, c)\times (-b,-c, 1)$ it will give you a vector that is parallel to the necessary first column vector of $A^{-1}$ then you multiply (1,a,b) by that vector to size it correctly.

$\frac{1}{1+a^2 + b^2+c^2}\begin {bmatrix} c^2-1\\a-bc\\ ac-b \end{bmatrix}$ is the first column vector.

By the way, are you sure it is a $-1$ in the middle there?  If it is then $\det A = -1+a^2 - b^2 + c^2$

Comment: I really like your clever use of linear algebra when you talk about the orthogonality of the second and third row vectors of $A$ to the first column of $A^{-1}$ but I think you need to add the same explanation or at least a simple remark about it for finding the other columns of $A^{-1}$ to make the answer complete. Plus, some explanations about why that orthogonality thing is true will definitely help the OP understand your answer better, I think. It's sort of vague as it is.